# Python + scrape strong within ul

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the information under the strong tag within ul.
I'm using the following code to extract strong:

```
stats = soup.find('ul', attrs = {'class' : 'inline-stats section'})
print(stats)
```

The print is shown in the image below.
Now, I need to extract the information within strong; that is 8.0 , 49.41 and 6.10.

I tried to loop over values in stats but always get errors and got stuck.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
<ul class="inline-stats section">
<li>
<strong>8.0<abbr class="unit" title="kilometers">km</abbr></strong>
<div class="label">Distance</div>
</li>
<li>
<strong>49:41</strong>
<div class="label">
<span class="glossary-link run-version" data-glossary-term="definition-moving-
time"></span>
Moving Time
</div>
</li>
<li>
<strong>6:10<abbr class="unit" title="minutes per kilometer">/km</abbr></strong>
<div class="label">
<span class="glossary-link run-version" data-glossary-term="definition-moving-
time">
Pace
</span>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: alway put data and errors as text. now we can't copy data to create example

Comment: you could create minimal-working-example.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: I've included all the information.

Comment: I said **FULL** **Traceback**. With current message it seems you have problem in different line of code - `Traceback` shows which line of code makes problem.

Comment: Probably in `stats` you have list with many results and you have to use `for` loop to get every element from `stats` before you use `find_all()`

Comment: Can't you just use something like: `stats = [n.text for n in soup.select('ul.inline-stats.section li strong')]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
stats = soup.find('ul', attrs = {'class' : 'inline-stats section'}).findAll("strong")
```

Add:

```
for i in stats:
    print i
```

Comment: Thanks Rinogg. This is helpful. This way I can extract all 3 strong tags text. However, do you think I can loop over it to generate 3 different values?

Comment: I've responded in the answer above

Comment: I have modified my first post trying a loop to generate 3 variables. Not sure why it does not work

Comment: `.findAll` is deprecated - `.find_all` should be preferred.

Comment: Thanks @Rinogg. I understood the problem. You've been very helpful